# Rspec & Factory Girl: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

On the tedious journey to learning TDD with Rspec, I ran into an error testing the controller create action for the nested object, comments. `Comments belong_to a Post`. I have had no luck finding the answer on Stack Overflow. Here is what I have so far.

The test.

**comments_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'shoulda-matchers'

RSpec.describe CommentsController, :type => :controller do

        describe '#GET create' do
            before :each do
              @post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
              post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment, post_id: @post)
            end

            it 'creates a comment' do
              expect(Comment.count).to eq(1)
            end
        end
end
```

The fail.

```
Failures:

  1) CommentsController#GET create creates a comment
     Failure/Error: post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment, post_id: @post)
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :comment=>{:name=>"MyString", :body=>"MyText", :post_id=>"1"}, :controller=>"comments"}
     # ./spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])

        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        redirect_to @post
    end


    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 root 'posts#index'

 resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

**rake routes**

```
☹ rake routes
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
             root GET    /                                           posts#index
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are sending the params like this:

```
:comment=>{:name=>"MyString", :body=>"MyText", :post_id=>"1"}
```

It should be:

```
:comment=>{:name=>"MyString", :body=>"MyText"}, :post_id=>"1"
```

This will find the route correctly.

Change the line:

```
post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment, post_id: @post)
```

to:

```
post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment), post_id: @post
```

Your controller will also need changing to:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

Comment: That worked! The change in the controller makes a lot more sense. Thank you.